# BlockCypher MicroTX transaction fee?

Tags: transactions, micropayments

does anyone know how much is the BlockCypher fee when doing Micro TX? I read here (https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#microtx) and it says it is generated automatically (deducted from source). I need specifics, like is it in % or a fixed value,  but cannot find any.

Answer (score 4):

The [Microtransaction API](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#microtransaction-api) documentation it describes a BlockCypher MicroTX as a normal transaction. BlockCypher just checks that the transaction has reached 98% on their [confidence-factor](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#confidence-factor) and is therefore included in the next block.

However the documentation (and the whole concept) seems to be outdated.

> The Microtransaction API will accept values between 7,000 satoshis (~$0.04) and 4,000,000 satoshis (~$20). Anything below or above these thresholds will return an error.

At the time of writing (BTC @ ~$7000) the 7000 satoshi would be worth ~$0.49. In the Microtransaction API they alert that MircoTX are **not** feasible anymore and the API is therefore discontinued on bitcoin.

> Due to congestion on the Bitcoin network and the drastic increase in miner fees, microtransactions have become uneconomical. As a result, our microtransaction API isn’t supported on bitcoin anymore.

Comment: Hi, thanks, so to, say transfer btc from one address to another, I have to use the Transaction API from here? https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#transaction-api

Comment: @user2002495 What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to send a bitcoin transaction? Do you have to use blockcypher?

Comment: yes i just want to send btc from one address to another. Reason I have to use blockcypher is because it is not only btc but need to be eth, lite, and doge as well.